# Does matching the character to the kart matter in Double Dash?

Tags: mario-kart-double-dash

From [here](http://www.cheatcc.com/gc/mariokdd.html):

> Each driver will go slightly faster if they are driving their own kart

I've seen this written elsewhere, but it all is just repeats of the same claim without evidence.

Also, later in the same article:

> It does not matter who you have driving; speeds remain the same no matter what character you choose to drive.

Given a particular kart, does character selection effect speed?

Answer (score 2):

You get no advantage by having the kart of one of the characters in your duo.

The only effect of character selection on your kart or stats is that you will always have a kart of the group of your heavier character.

As you may know there are three types, light, medium and heavy. This goes for the characters and for the karts.

So if you pick a heavy char and a light char, you will have to take a heavy kart, if you take two medium chars you will get a medium kart, and so on.

What is important for your stats is the kart you take, each kart has his own statistics (Top-speed, off-road speed, acceleration and weight) you can find the exact list on this website : http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart:_Double_Dash!!